# SCNAction Retain Cycles?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I've started to play around with Instruments and have found that my small Scenekit game contains many memory leaks, up to 100 at a time. Most of the leaked objects are **SCNActionFade, SCNCActionFade, SCNActionMove, SCNCActionMove, SCNActionRepeat** and **SCNCActionRepeat.**

I'll discuss **SCNActionFade** since it's the most simplest part of my code

```
/* Fade Out */
func fadeOut(node: SCNNode, duration: Double) {
    let fadeOutAction = SCNAction.fadeOutWithDuration(duration)
    node.runAction(fadeOutAction, completionHandler: { -> Void in
        node.removeAllActions()
        node.removeFromParentNode()
    })
}
```

[image: SCNActionFade Retain Cycle]

At first I thought the problem was with the `-> Void in` part, so I changed it to `unowned in` and `weak in` but that didn't stop the retain cycle. I've done research on this before posting here but I'm stumped.

Also, fadeOut is called within `func renderer(renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) {` only when the if statement is true. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the `func renderer` code.

Comment: @P3rry Did you ever find out what was causing the retain cycles to occur in this or other SceneKit apps? Thanks!